# How to sync Google Photo from phone to mac?

Tags: mac, google, google-apps, google-photos

As of July 10, that's changing. Google says that Drive sync was causing confusion with users, so Photos will no longer include an option to sync with Google Drive.

Is there any idea for seamless way to sync?

some of my search

https://www.pcworld.com/article/3407780/google-photos-backup-drive-auto-sync.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use other service to sync photo e.g. dropbox or LR

and put that folder in your gDrive so it sync with gDrive and you got photo from you phone

https://support.google.com/photos/thread/13415041?hl=en